# wordpress "path to 'Home' points to localhost"

Tags: php, wordpress, localhost, remote-server

Main issue.
When I click on the 'Home' tab on the Wordpress site, it points to localhost.

Troubleshooting steps already taken.
1.
From cpanel >phpmyadmin > database > wp_options:

In MySQL wp_options

```
Siteurl shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolioDecember
Home shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolioDecember
```

2.
WordPress Dashboard

```
Settings > general >
Wordpress address(URL) shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolioDecember
Site Address (URL) shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolioDecember/
```

3.
WordPress Dashboard

```
Settings > reading >
```

Front page displays your last posts

What happened.
I developed locally and I uploaded  my final site to my Remote Host.
I wanted to do some housekeeping to remove unnecessary pages and posts.
I did this while logged into

```
shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolioDecember
```

and from the dashboard.

I believe that I renamed a page - maybe the one called 'front' to 'about' but I do not think that matters.
Now when I click on the HOME TAB,
the url points to

```
http://localhost:8888/projectPortfolioDecember/
```

and the browser error is

```
"This Website is not available."
```

To troubleshoot, I compared two sites below, both of which have the HOME TAB.

This first site was a learning site.

```
http://shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolio
```

If you click on any Tab and then click on the HOME TAB to return, it works.

```
Inspect Element > <a href="http://www.shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolio/">Home</a>
```

This is my final site.

```
http://shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolioDecember/
```

If you click on any Tab and then click on the HOME TAB , it says'

```
Inspect Element >
<a href="http://localhost:8888/projectPortfolioDecember/" onclick="__gaTracker('send', 'event', 'outbound-widget', 'http://localhost:8888/projectPortfolioDecember/', 'Home');">Home</a>
```

[imgur link that shows the above two screen side by side][1]

![enter image description here][1]

Here is the link to the image on imgur.

```
http://imgur.com/delete/n2A8WL3NTlPn8kx
```

I cannot find the file or code to fix this ?
Please help ?

notes.
I have manually looked everywhere in the code.
I understand a lot of theme development - the php, mysql, configuration .... 
When I look at all of my pages from the wordpress dashboard, I never see a 'home page' or the page that would be the index.php.
When I look in all of the .php file from my IDE I cannot find the code where the path to 'home' or index.php is defined.
And within the database, the siteurl and home are set to this path:

```
shareyourpeace2.info/projectPortfolioDecember  (no ending slash)
```

Comment: Have you checked your page template? How about your menu definition in the Admin?

Comment: Thanks.  Please check this link. It is obvious you know about the issue and this is hanging me up.

Comment: :)  short and quick. thank you a ton :)  appearance > menus > edit menus > home > popdown > change path from localhost:8888 .... to shareyourpeace2.info/projectProfileDecember. really. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also update the `guid` values for every page and post in the `wp-posts` table. You can do this with an `REPLACE` command in phpMyAdmin:

```
UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = replace(guid, 'http://www.old-domain.com','http://www.new-domain.com');
```

See [this post for more info.](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/updating-links-in-old-posts-when-things-change)